# iOS: App opens view life cycle methods are not called if app was in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to open specific view controller if user opens app from url. But i am facing the problem, if user tap on home button and open app through URL, App opens in its last state because view life cycle methods are not called. Therefore, I am unable to navigate the view to task detail screen. I want, if user open app through url if it is in background then it should open the specific View controller.
PS: I cant terminate the app.
Following code i am using (code is written in AppDelegate.m):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    if([UserName length]!=0 && [Password length]!=0)
    {
        NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
        NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
        NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
        NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
        // NSDictionary *dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
        // NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);

        NSArray* query = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString: @"&"];
        NSString *taskId = [query objectAtIndex: 0];
        NSString *taskType = [query objectAtIndex: 1];
        NSArray* taskIdArray= [taskId componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];
        NSArray* taskTypeArray = [taskType componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];
        taskId = [taskIdArray objectAtIndex: 1];
        taskType = [taskTypeArray objectAtIndex: 1];
        NSLog(@"%@,%@",taskId,taskType);

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        ActivityDetailController *destViewController = (ActivityDetailController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ActivityDetailView"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];  
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You have to adjust your view state to match what you want to do.  What is the precise problem you are having?  Add methods in the appropriate places which you can call from `handleOpenURL`.

Comment: I want to open a view controller if user is coming from url, but when i open that view controller using above code; nothing happens.

Comment: The view which opens again, no view life cycle method of that class called.

Comment: View just restore its previous state.

Comment: Have you set URL schemes under  URL Types?

Comment: Yes I have set URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open app every time at `ActivityDetailController` when come to foreground then you can do this,

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ActivityDetailController *destViewController = (ActivityDetailController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ActivityDetailView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES];  
}
```

in `applicationWillEnterForeground` or `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: No i only want to open this if user is coming from url .. i am using above coe but it is not working for me.

Comment: then you put condition to check that user coming from url then do this else nothing

Comment: I am doing this .. but if app is in background, app is opens from url .. this code doesn't work, app just restore its previous state.